# How to set the VB Editor default directory?

Tags: vba, ide, vbe

How does one set the default directory for the VBA Editor?

This ought to be obvious in any application, not to mention an obligatory feature, but I can't figure it out.

Having to navigate up and over my directory structure from an irrelevant /user/documents directory every time I import or export a module is nuts.

Comment: Look at `ENVIRON`  https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/515140-list-of-environ-expressions.html     Something like so i think http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/02/26/get-the-path-to-my-documents-in-vba/

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful even if the answer really is that the VB Editor default directory can't be set.

Comment: Apologies, I thought you were working out how to export to a folder from VBA code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the VB Editor default directory can't be set.

The best that can be done is to configure the OS to map the user's Documents directory elsewhere.